# How to get the most occurred database rows with php

Tags: php, sql, database, count

I don't know how to phrase this, but I'm trying to get the rows with the most occurrences in the column to display, for example

```
ID   from_id      to_id
1    1            3
2    1            3
3    1            3 
4    1            3 
5    2            3
6    3            3
7    3            3
8    4            3
9    4            3
```

I'm trying to get 1,4,3 from the database because it's more frequent, how would I do this?
Sorry if it's a bad question, I don't know how to phrase it

Comment: How is 2 more frequent than 4?

Comment: It's an error, I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy, just `COUNT(from_id)`, eg like this

```
SELECT from_id, COUNT(from_id) AS total FROM your_table 
GROUP BY from_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

You can now modify this, eg `LIMIT 10` to get the top 10 or `WHERE total > 1` before the `GROUP BY` to only get rows which occure more than once.